# Need to design html page for Thermal Printer in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, webforms

I am developing my application in asp.net web forms. I  want to print my receipt in thermal printer. Currently my receipt is printing in normal A4 size page. I want to print that receipt also in thermal printer. What do I do? If I redesign the receipt for thermal printer then what should be the width of div how to redesign it. or any other method by which I use currently design also for thermal paper print. Kindly guide me.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use responsive-design techniques, add a `media` rule where the page-width is 6cm or however wide your thermal printer's paper is, then re-layout the page accordingly.

That's all I can say for now as your question is missing important details, such as the existing markup and styles of your receipt page.